# How to represent data with meaning dependent on other columns?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

This question is about relational databases like postgresql or oracle. The following is a toy example of my problem. Say I have five tables

```
Client (id, name)
1 Joe
2 Ted

Factory (id, name, salary)
1 BMW     20
2 Porsche 30

Farm (id, name, salary)
1 Wineyard    10
2 Cattle farm  5

Occupation
1 Farmer
2 Worker

Client_Occupation (client-id, occupation-id, dependent-id)
1 (Joe) 1 (Farmer) 1 (Wineyard)
2 (Ted) 2 (Worker) 2 (Porsche)
```

To find out how much Joe earns, the sql needs to use data from either the table farms (if the occupation id is 1) or factories (if the occupation id is 2). This is creating very convoluted queries and makes the processing code more complex than it should be.

Is there a better way to structure this data if I do not want to merge the factories and farms tables?

---

In other words: the table client_ocupation has a conditional relation to either Farm or Factory. Is there a better way to represent this information?

```
                 Client
                   ^
                   |
Factory <-  Client_Occupation -> Farm
                   |
                   v
               Occupation
```

Comment: If you are using an SQL database, you can use Foreign Keys: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: @Err Yes, the point is that I am looking for a better structure which avoids having the foreign key to point to either the Farm or Factory tables.

Comment: Why can't you merge Farm and Factory? The current data structure suggests that Farms and Factories are nothing more than 'Locations'.

Comment: @Marisa Its just an explanatory example, these tables are actually huge.

Comment: @Marisa Furthermore, in the real case there are about a dozen linked tables.

Comment: @Err Whether FKs & other constraints are declared has no bearing on what queries return or what the meaning of a query is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes up often when [modeling OO hierarchies](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server), and is a table inheritance pattern. Generally, I prefer [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) over [Single Table Inheritance](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html), but they both have their use cases.

Single Table Inheritance is really easy - just take your `Farm` and `Factory` tables and merge them together for a superset. Done and done. Unfortunately, those niceties things like constraints become difficult, and you'll find yourself writing a lot of `CASE` expressions on the discriminator column.

Concrete Table Inheritance takes a little time to grok, but is actually pretty simple as well. You design a base table w/common attributes and a discriminator column, and then "sub" tables w/specific attributes for each level of the hierarchy. The sub tables are linked back to the base table by Id and Discriminator - which provides some query optimizer gains and prevents a single entity from being multiple types.

For your example problem, you really don't have any specific attributes on the leaves - so this will look a little odd, but the pattern still works (note that I'm renaming "dependent-id" to "location-id" to make it more understandable):

```
Occupation (id, name)
1 Farmer
2 Worker

# the base table for all locations w/common attributes
Location (id, type, name, salary)
# unique constraint on discriminator column, and another on the combination of id and type so that we can reference in a foreign key
PK(id), UC(type), UC(id, type)
1 Farm Wineyard 10
2 Farm Cattle farm 5
3 Factory BMW 20
4 Factory Porsche 30

Client_Occupation (client-id, occupation-id, location-id)
FK location-id => location.id
1 (Joe) 1 (Farmer) 3 (Wineyard)
2 (Ted) 2 (Worker) 1 (Porsche)

Farm
# carry the discriminator column and check constraint it; any Farm specific columns can be added here
PK(id), FK(id, type) => location(id, type), CHECK type = 'Farm'
Factory (id, type)
1 Farm
2 Farm

Factory
# carry the discriminator column and check constraint it; any Factory specific columns can be added here
PK(id), FK(id, type) => location(id, type), CHECK type = 'Factory'
Factory (id, type)
3 Factory
4 Factory
```

You can now easily get salary for everything applicable:

```
SELECT * FROM Client_Occupation CO JOIN Location L ON CO.location-id = L.id
```

And, if you want to get specific `Farm` columns, or limit it to `Farm` locations:

```
SELECT * FROM Client_Occupation CO JOIN Location L ON CO.location-id = L.id
JOIN Farm F ON CO.id = F.id and CO.type = F.type // technically, joining on type is unnecessary, but I prefer to include it anyway
```

And, if you want to emulate the Single Table inheritance model:

```
SELECT * FROM Client_Occupation CO JOIN Location L ON CO.location-id = L.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Farm F ON CO.id = F.id and CO.type = F.type 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Factory T ON CO.id = T.id and CO.type = T.type
```

On occasion, it's difficult to refactor an existing table design into this pattern. In that case, a view for your base table provides a lot of the same querying benefits:

```
CREATE VIEW Location AS
   SELECT id, 'Farm' as type, name, salary FROM Farm
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, 'Factory' as type, name, salary FROM Factory
```

At that point, you will (probably) have conflicting ids (eg., a FarmId = 1 and FactoryId = 1) so you'll need to be diligent about including the `type` column in any joins.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, `Farm` and `Factory` should be merged to `Workplace` and then `Workplace` could have additional attribute called `Type` which could take the value *Farm* or *Factory*. So the table would look somewhat like this:

```
Workplace
---------

Id  Name         Salary  Type
--  ----         ------  ----
1   BMW          20      Factory
2   Cattle Farm  5       Farm
.
.
```

Your problem's root is bad design, not a lack of skill to write good enough queries.

---

Now that it is fixed in the question that you can't merge `Farm` and `Factory`, answering your question:

> Is there a better way to structure this data if I do not want to merge the factories and farms tables?

No matter however you structure the data, as long as the tables are different, you will have to write the logic to figure out which table to query. So that *convolution* is inevitable if you keep `Farm` and `Factory` separated and follow proper design otherwise. But you can hide this convolution behind the scenes. Create views from the query on tables you have to often join. Now rather than performing query between three tables, you write the query between one table and the view generated from the query on other two.

Comment: The table client_occupation is there because a client can have more than one job.